# Is $\{ X(A) : A \in \mathcal{F} \} $ a $\sigma$ - Algebra?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Let $( \Omega, \mathcal{F}, P )$ be a probability space a let $X : \Omega \to \mathbb{R} $ be a random variable. My question is:

Is $\{ X(A) : A \in \mathcal{F} \} $ a $\sigma$ - Algebra ?

My attempt: NO a sigma algebra. If we consider $X: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $X(x) = x^2$, then $X(\mathbb{R}) = (0, \infty) \implies (X(\mathbb{R}))^c = (- \infty , 0 )$ My claim is that there is not an $A \in \mathcal{F}$ such that $(X(\mathbb{R}))^c = X(A) $. But, Im stuck trying to show this. Can someone help me?

Comment: What did you try? Which parts are stopping you? I am asking this because pondering quietly during one minute the axioms a sigma-algebra must fulfill should show you the answer. Otherwise, there is a mystery we must solve before answering...

Comment: I think there is a mistery

Comment: @Did : I have updated my answer with my try. Can you judge me now?

Comment: "Judge", no, comment, yes. In your example, you could ask yourself whether $\mathbb R$ is in $\{X(A)\mid A\in\mathcal F\}$.

Comment: I would love to be judged by you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MY PREVIOUS ANSWER WAS INCORRECT. I'M SORRY.**

Let $\Omega=\{-1,0,1\}$ and $\mathscr{F}=\left\{\varnothing,\{1\},\{-1,0\},\{-1,0,1\}\right\}$. Clearly, $\mathscr{F}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Now, let $X(a)=a^2$ for all $a\in\Omega$ and $\mathscr{G}\equiv\{X(A):A\in\mathscr{F}\}$. It is not difficult to compute that $$\mathscr{G}=\left\{\varnothing,\{1\},\{0,1\}\right\}.$$ This is **not** a $\sigma$-algebra, since $\{0\}$, which is the complement of $\{1\}$, is not contained in it.

Comment: thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Thank you, this was a challenging one! The mistake I made in the wrong proof was that I assumed that $B=X(A)$ implied that $A=X^{-1}(B)$, which is not true. In fact, all that $B=X(A)$ implies is that $A\subseteq X^{-1}(B)$.